# ActiveRecord callbacks on associations that are replaced by a new collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

Callbacks on objects which are updated during removal from a relationship collection don't seem to be executing for me.

I have a model EntityLocation which serves as a polymorphic relationship between Entities (Users/Places/Things) and Locations (Zips, Addresses, Neighborhoods).

```
class EntityLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entity, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :location, :polymorphic => true

  def after_save
    if entity_id.nil? || location_id.nil?
      # Delete me since I'm no longer associated to an entity or a location
      destroy
    end
  end
end
```

For this example, lets assume that I have a "Thing" with a collection of "Locations", referenced by my_thing.locations. This returns a collection of Zip, Address, etc.

If I write the code

```
my_thing.locations = [my_thing.locations.create(:location => Zip.find(3455))]
```

then as expected a new EntityLocation is created and can be accurately referenced from my_thing.locations. However the problem is that the records which were previously contained within this collection are now orphaned in the database with a nil entity_id attribute. I'm trying to delete these objects in the after_save callback, however it's never getting executed on the old object.

I've also tried using an after_update, and after_remove and neither gets called on the old record. The newly created record after_save callback does get called as expected, but that doesn't help me.

Does Rails update the previously referenced object without executing the callback chain through active record?  All ideas appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why does this need to be polymorphic? It seems that you could simply use `has_many :through` to model the many-to-many relationship.

Secondly, why not simply delete the join table row through the association with `:dependent => :destroy`? Then you don't need a custom callback

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entity_locations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :locations, :through => :entity_locations
end

class EntityLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entity
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entity_locations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :entities, :through => :entity_locations
end
```

Now deleting from either side deletes the join table row as well.

Comment: Thanks. The reason it's a polymorphic relationship is because there is no class Entity, nor class Location. An Entity is an instance of User, Place, or Thing. A Location is an instance of Zip, Address, or Neighborhood. Therefore EntityLocation model is polymorphic in that it has entity_type, entity_id, location_type, and location_id fields.

Nonetheless, I'd like to accomplish the behavior you described despite the fact it's polymorphic. Maybe I'm just missing the correct Rails syntax?

Comment: It looks like you want "double-sided polymorphism", which as far as I know is not possible without some hacking of Rails itself. You should take a look at the has_many_polymorphs gem: https://github.com/fauna/has_many_polymorphs. I'm not sure if it's updated for Rails3, but it may help.